# When to use "to be" with "come"?

Tags: present-perfect

I noticed people using "we are come", "he is come", etc. in older texts but some not too old (J.R.R. Tolkien uses it occasionally in The Lord of the Rings). Is this valid contemporary English (bookish, perhaps)? Are there situations in which I should use this construction? Or is it considered archaic?

Comment: It is archaic.  It sounds Biblical to me, like "he is risen."

Comment: With fiction you should consider that usage is according to the contextual time frame, not when it was written. I wouldn't use modern fictional works to describe modern usage you can't find elsewhere.

Comment: As an aside, I suspect using *to be* instead of *to have* used to be a rule in English for at least some verbs.  It's still that way in German - for example, "Er *ist* gegangen", not "Er *hat* gegangen".

Answer (score 1):

In your examples "come" is usually replace by "here" in modern speech

> He is *here*.
>   We are *here*.

more often you may find "*to have*" used instead of *to be*

> He *has* come.
>   We *have* come.
>   We *have* arrived.